# Malloc and Struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

i am facing some difficulties with malloc and structs. I want to read the m_data.number_chars as shown in my code (which is an integer) to be the memory that i want to allocate.. But when i compile my code, and run it, it crushes.. Any ideas..?  Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct movies {
int number_chars;
char name;
int made_year;
float money;
};
struct movies m_data;


int main()
{
   scanf("%d",&m_data.number_chars);
   m_data.name=malloc(m_data.number_chars);
   gets(m_data.name);
   printf("%s",m_data.name);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",m_data.number_chars);`->`scanf("%d",&m_data.number_chars);` and then I was scrolling through your code and saw it ... **`gets`** avoid it- shun it.

Comment: @coderredoc lol yeee, just saw it... My bad.. Thanks for seeing it! Have a nice day.

Comment: @user3121023 isnt fgets just for files though..?

Comment: First, include <stdlib.h> to use malloc. malloc returns pointer, you are assigning it to char name. Then you do gets() on that name.

Comment: stdin is a file

Comment: What is your input? You also have to account for the terminating null. Allocate at least 1 + your string length. Welcome to C programming by the way. Don't forget to call free() also, or you get memory leaks.

Comment: @Makketronix i type 5 and then it stops working.

Comment: @JonathanWood Crushing because i use codeblocks..

Comment: ah. use &m_data.number_chars for scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you were supposed to pass `char*` to the `scanf` - more specifically address of the variable on which input will be stored. You didn't do that.

No return value check for the standard functions and ofcourse you didn't use `malloc` earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct movies {
    int number_chars;
    char* name;
    int made_year;
    float money;
};
struct movies m_data;


int main(void)
{
    if( scanf("%d",&m_data.number_chars)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    getchar();
    if(m_data.number_chars <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in number of character count");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    m_data.name = malloc(m_data.number_chars+1);
    if(!m_data.name){
        perror("Malloc error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(fgets(m_data.name,m_data.number_chars+1,stdin)){
        printf("[%s]\n",m_data.name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It misses one char!. For eg. If i put 5 for the number chars, and i read achil,
it will print achi

Comment: @AchilleasGuru.: Nope there is extra `\n`.

Comment: @AchilleasGuru.: As an easy way out I have added one extra `char` to incorporate this. But yes just read the manual for `fgets` you can modify those small cchanges then yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `scanf`, you need to pass the address of the variable to hold the result (using the ampersand `&`). This would definitely cause serious memory problems right there.

Also, `name` is of type `char`. `char` is not a pointer. Therefore, you cannot assign the result of `malloc()` to `name`.

You need a pointer type.

Also, "crushes" is not a technical description of what is going wrong. You'll probably get further if you can articulate your situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct movies {
int number_chars;
char *name;
int made_year;
float money;
};
struct movies m_data;


int main()
{
   scanf("%d",&m_data.number_chars);
   m_data.name=malloc(m_data.number_chars);
   gets(m_data.name);
   printf("%s",m_data.name);
   free(m_data.name)
}
```